# Ruby hash direct access vs merge

Tags: ruby

Is there any difference between:

```
@attr[:field] = new_value
```

and

```
@attr.merge(:field => new_value)
```

Comment: this is not rails specific, it is pure ruby afaik

Comment: yep, so used to say Rails that sometimes I forget what is pure Ruby, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using `merge!` instead of `merge`, there is no difference.
The only difference is that you can use multiple fields (meaning: another hash) in the merge parameters.

Example:

```
   h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
   h2 = { "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }
   h3 = h1.merge(h2)    
   puts h1         # => {"a" => 100, "b" => 200}
   puts h3         # => {"a"=>100, "b"=>254, "c"=>300}
   h1.merge!(h2)   
   puts h1         # => {"a"=>100, "b"=>254, "c"=>300}
```

When assigning single values, I would prefer `h[:field] = new_val` over `merge` for readability reasons and **I guess** it is faster than merging.

You can also take a look at the Hash-rdoc: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000759

Answer (score 3):

They do the same thing, however:

```
@attr[:field] = new_value
```

is more efficient, since no hash traversing is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

**Merge** returns a new hash at a different location merging other_hashes into self
but **Merge!** operated like "update" returning self hash, copying at self-location.

```
    h1 = { "a": 1 }
    h2 = { "b": 2 }

    def merge_hash (h1,h2)
      puts h1                 # {:a=> 1}
      puts h1.object_id       # 340720
  
      h1 = h1.merge(h2)
      puts h1                 # {:a=>1, :b=>2}
      puts h1.object_id       # 340760
    end

    merge_hash(h1, h2)
    puts h1                     # {:a=>1}
    puts h1.object_id           # 340720


    def merge_hash (h1,h2)
      puts h1                 # {:a=>1}
      puts h1.object_id       # 340720
  
      h1 = h1.merge!(h2)
      puts h1                 # {:a=>1, :b=>2}
      puts h1.object_id       # 340720
    end

    merge_hash(h1, h2)
    puts h1                     # {:a=>1, :b=>2}
    puts h1.object_id           # 340720
```

Comment: Perfect! this is something I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-bang merge to use hashes in a functional programming style.

Ruby Functional Programming has under [Don't update variables](http://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming#Don%27t_update_variables)

> Don't update hashes
>
> No:

```
hash = {:a => 1, :b => 2}
hash[:c] = 3
hash
```

> Yes:

```
hash = {:a => 1, :b => 2}
new_hash = hash.merge(:c => 3)
```